# Regex is working in local machine. But in the production machine, it is not working

Tags: c#, regexp-replace

Basically, I am trying to remove special character from xml file. I have tried the below code. I have tested with regex tester. It's working fine. In the production machine, it is replacing string.Empty for = character which is valid.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlString = "<root><name>John & = Doe</name></root>";

        // Replace special characters with their XML entities
        string cleanedXml = Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"[^\u09\u0A\u0D\u20-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFFF]", 
                                       string.Empty);
    
        Console.WriteLine(cleanedXml);
    }

}
```

Culture : en-US in the prod machine.

Please anyone help me on this why it's happening. What's problem in the regex expression? Why regex is replacing equal symbol on prod machine alone? I am using. Net framework 4.8 version.

Comment: On production is it removing all special chars and also equals? Or is it just removing equals? Are you looking at the raw XML when assessing this or are you looking at some prettified, decoded version of it?

Comment: @flackoverstow - It is removing equals (=)  and &lt; (<) and &gt; when receive in the xml file.

Comment: Pattern seems to be invalid, by the way - did you mean `@"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]"` ? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Or maybe `[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]` ? `\x` expects 2 digits, `\u` expects 4

Comment: @flackoverstow - I used this one string InvalidXmlCharactersRange = @"[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD\x10000-x10FFFF]". This regex pattern is working fine and not replacing equal (=) & greater than (>) and less than (<) symbols in the local machine and working fine in Regex tester as well. But same regex pattern is replacing string.empty for equal (=) & greater than (>) and less than (<) symbols in the production environment. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1374012/how-to-validate-xml-dataset-when-hexadecimal-inval

Comment: @flackoverstow Valid char range - #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] - https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets

Comment: **Required reading** [why you shouldn't use Regex for XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997). Use a proper XML parser instead, such as `XDocument`.